# Loop works from 6 Element Only (link) Requests

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm Producing An Algorithm That Filter [Brainly.com](https://brainly.com.br/) Site Links And Turn Them Into `Lists`, **CODE BELOW**:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import requests

browser =webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:/path/geckodriver.exe')
browser.get('https://brainly.com.br/app/ask?entry=hero&q=15+12')
WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'a[href*="/tarefa"]')))
html=browser.page_source
#html = browser.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
p=[]
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
for link in soup.select('div.sg-actions-list__hole > a[href*="/tarefa"]'):
    ref=link.get('href')
    rt = ('https://brainly.com.br'+str(ref))
    p.append(rt)
print(p)

for url in p:
    print(requests.get(url).text) 

Output Generated List:

['https://brainly.com.br/tarefa/4726592', 'https://brainly.com.br/tarefa/2645408', 'https://brainly.com.br/tarefa/1610749', 'https://brainly.com.br/tarefa/6008293', 'https://brainly.com.br/tarefa/13872231', 'https://brainly.com.br/tarefa/22541768', 'https://brainly.com.br/tarefa/4531702', 'https://brainly.com.br/tarefa/23553975', 'https://brainly.com.br/tarefa/7061395', 'https://brainly.com.br/tarefa/13037193']
```

My Problem Getting Loop Only to Work From 6 Link: `https://brainly.com/tarefa/4531702`

I need the loop:

for url in p:
            print(requests.get(url).text)

Print the Source Code of All Links. So After I Can Filter Them.

Comment: What do you mean by "Print the Source Code of All Links" ?

Comment: Pass Each Url Through a = Requests.get (url) and then print (a.text).